# Java and MongoDb Intersect Query

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spatial-query

I am trying to make `geoIntersects` queries using MongoDB with java driver.

I have two collections:

- one called `countries` that contains geojson of country polygons
- another called `publications` that contains an article field with a coordinate field.

I want to find what country each paper is in to display on a map. 
I have currently tried:

```
if(author.getAffiliation().getSelectedWikiarticle() != null) {
   WikipediaArticleImpl article = author.getAffiliation().getSelectedWikiarticle();
   CleanedCoordinatesImpl cleanedCoords = article.getCleanedCoords();
   FindIterable<org.bson.Document> result = collection.find(Filters.geoIntersects("geometry", (Bson) cleanedCoords));
   System.out.println(result.first());
}
```

I iterate through the papers and get the individual coordinates and then try to run intersect on the countries collection geometry field. This throws a `500 error`. I have tried not casting it to Bson which doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks

### Edit

Here is the structure of the data:

#### country json

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5ee2701569b36402399acac7"
   },
   "type":"Feature",
   "id":"AFG",
   "properties":{
      "name":"Afghanistan"
   },
   "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
         [
            [
               61.210817,
               35.650072
            ],
            [
               62.230651,
               35.270664
            ],
     ...
```

#### cleanedCoords

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5ea1f0cf8473911346e96f1a"
   },
   "metadata":{
      "title":"some title",
      "authors":[
         {
            "first":"Daria",
            "middle":[

            ],
            "last":"Bulanova",
            "suffix":"",
            "affiliation":{
               "laboratory":"",
               "institution":"University of Helsinki",
               "locationSettlement":"Helsinki",
               "locationCountry":"Finland",
               "selectedWikiarticle":{
                    ...
                  "cleanedCoords":{
                     "type":"Point",
                     "coordinates":[
                        60.170833333333334,
                        24.9375
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
         },
         ...
}
```

also there is no personal data in any of this. It is all free publicly available datasets

Comment: Can you post please your sample data, seems like your entities are not correct. `cleanedCoords` should have similar syntax as this: `geoIntersects("geometry", new Point(new Position(4, 0)))`

Comment: @Valijon sure I added it above. CleanedCoords is a coordinate pair saved in a different collection.

Comment: Add please your sample data as text

Comment: @Valijon sure added above